# What animation tools to use in developing a Non-English Speech to Sign language translator software?

Tags: software-development, 3d, animation

The system is supposed to provide a real-time translation of speech to sign language. I will be using Kaldi for the speech recognition and python NLP libraries for language processing? However, I don’t know what tools to use for the animation part.

Comment: Do you ***really*** need animation? I can see that it would be very useful, but can you develop v1.0 just using flashcard images, to allow the project to progress, while continuing this search?

Comment: Yes, using animation is a requirement

Comment: That's a***lot*** of work, depending on how many words & phrases you have